# ajax function database update not working

Tags: ajax

The following function is not working. Database is updated when sending data directly to php script using form action but when sent to php script through AJAX function the database is not updated but I receive success message.

the ajax

```
<script src="ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

 function addRecord()
{
var first_first_name= $('#first_firstname').val();
var first_last_name = $('#first_lastname').val();
var team_name = $('#team_name').val();

 if(team_name == ' '){
    $('#propspectDiv').html('Enter A Valid Name');
    $('#TeamName').addClass('error');
    return;
        }else{
$('#TeamName').removeClass('error');
$('#propspectDiv').removeClass('error');
$('#propspectDiv').html('Entering Team Name.<img src="images/processing.gif" />');
 $.ajax({url : 'rpmh_open_update_prospects.php',
data:{
 "team_name" : team_name,
 "first_firstname" : first_first_name,
 "first_lastname" : first_last_name,
},
 success : function(data){
window.setTimeout(function()
{
$('#propspectDiv').html('Team Name Added!');
$('#data').css("display","block");
$('#data').html(data);
}, 2000);
}
});
}
}
 </script>


The php


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE mytable SET Team=? WHERE FirstName = ? AND LastName = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $team, $first, $last);

$team = $_POST['team_name'];
$first = $_POST['first_firstname'];
$last = $_POST['first_lastname'];

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: url : 'rpmh_open_update_prospects.php' after this add type:"POST"

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `GET` the default type of your `.ajax` method ?
Since you use `POST` you should precise it if it's the case.

In JQuery you would add `type: 'POST'`